# Apache Jmeter response time too high for web pages

Tags: jmeter

We are using Apache JMeter for the performance testing of web application. Apparently response time is too high in comparison to loading page in browser during load. When we open the page during load it opens in 2 seconds however JMeter reports 70 seconds. I understand  browser memory cache and disk cache are used in browser however isn't JMeter cache manager does same. How to assert it, comparing response header is one option. Any thoughts on this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It may be wrong configuration in the script. There won't be much difference between web browser and Jmeter response times (browser rendering time is ignored in Jmeter, not a big factor but must be considered)

If you are using single Http Sampler for a web page and retrieving all resources in tha page, then select "Parallel Downloads" option to '6' in Http sampler advanced section. So, you are simulating the browser behaviour of parallel downloading of the resources like .js, .css, images etc.

If you recorded the script using Test Script Recorder, then there will be an Http Sampler for each resource requet for that page which will be sent sequentially, hence increase in response time. You might be in this case, as of now, there is no feature/option to send the http samplers in parallel. so I suggest using the approach of adding one sampler, use parallel download of resources option in Http Sampler advanced section.

Also, caching is an important factor which decides the response time. Adding Http Cache manager can solve the issue in jmeter. This simulates browser behaviour of caching. I don't think there will be huge difference b/w browser and jmeter in implementing caching althought may not be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

The reason could be the lack of resources on JMeter machine or JMeter not being properly configured for producing high loads. JMeter default configuration is good for load tests development and debugging, you can run load tests up to certain amount of virtual users, but if you need to conduct a really high loads - you need to perform some configuration changes.

First of all, double check my guess using [jvisualvm](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html) and your operating system monitoring tools (there is [PerfMon JMeter Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/) which can be used for monitoring different metrics on application under test and JMeter load generators sides). If it is the case - take the next steps to get the most performance of your JMeter installation:

1. Increase [JVM Heap Size, NewSize, switch to ConcurrentMarkSweep Garbage Collector](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/hotspotfaq-138619.html).
2. Run your test in [non-GUI mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui).
3. Disable all the [listeners](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#listeners) during the test.
4. Follow other recommendations from [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) article.